# python compare lists and replace list element

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, comparison

I need to replace string `'default'` with `'custom'` if previous element in list exist in second list. I'm looking for better solution and more Pythonic way to do this.

```
base_list = [[1, 'post', 'default'], 
             [2, 'reply', 'default'],
             [3, 'register', 'default']]

custom_list = ['post', 'register']


for element in custom_list:
    for item in base_list:
        if element == item[1]:
            item[2] = 'custom'

print base_list
>>> [[1, 'post', 'custom'], [2, 'reply', 'default'], [3, 'register', 'custom']]
```

Comment: typically if your code "works" and has no bugs, code improvement questions should be moved to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with list comprehension as follows:

```
[[item[0], item[1], 'custom'] if item[1] in custom_list else item for item in base_list]
# Output: [[1, 'post', 'custom'], [2, 'reply', 'default'], [3, 'register', 'custom']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `in` operator:

```
for item in base_list:
    if item[1] in custom_list:
        item[2] = 'custom'
```

if `custom_list` is big, I'd make it a `set`.